# File creation is ignoring my parameters but creates an "Untitled" binary file

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

Using the Google API via the [googleapis package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) and the file.create call simply does not work. I've experimented making the same call in [Google's API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create) and it does work. I'm at a bit of a loss.

The createSheet call is encapsulated as follows :

```
Google.prototype.createSheet = function(filename, callback) {
    var services = google.drive('v3');
    services.files.create({
      "name"     : filename,
      "mimeType" : "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
      "description" : 'auto-generated by the cli',
      "auth"     : this.auth
    }, function(err,response) {
      if( err ) {
        console.log('Error : unable to create file, ' + err);
        return;
      } else {
        console.dir(response);
      }
    });
}
```

... the net result is,

```
{ kind: 'drive#file',
  id: '0BwWAQdfAgbYzWk5XRFQyODQ0Zmc',
  name: 'Untitled',
  mimeType: 'application/octet-stream' 
}
```

It's missing both the filename as well as the filetype.

The general framework here is working correctly as I can get a list of files and read from spreadsheets.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nodejs but I found some good resources that can help you understand the implementation should be- [Google's officially supported Node.js client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client) and related SO [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18006745/5995040)'s answer provided an article about uploading image in google drive with nodejs library. Hope this helps.

Comment: No luck. I can do the basic stuff. Just not create a spreadsheet.

Comment: Related... I started another question on the same topic but using the Google Sheets API - http://stackoverflow.com/q/40444281/391146

Comment: I have found a solution using the Spreadsheet API in the above post.